# Installing running elasticsearch on Windows 7 : Error in path

Tags: java, elasticsearch, installation

I am trying to install elasticsearch on Windows7.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/running-elasticsearch.html

I installed Java in following folder

> C:\java

If not set JAVA_HOME and running elasticsearch, getting error that JAVA_HOME is not set.

Set JAVA_HOME to 
C:\java\bin

When try to run elasticsearch getting this error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 4):

generally the common practice is as follows:

`JAVA_HOME` should be path to the root java directory, eg. `JAVA_HOME=C:\java`
and in the PATH there should be `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: @nishantsaxena: don't forget to accept this answer, by clicking on the tick mark to the left.